# Call SQL Server UDF in LINQ query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, user-defined-functions, edmx

I have this UDF in SQL Server: [dbo].[ObtieneEdad]

This definition in EDMX file:

```
<Function Name="ObtieneEdad" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="true" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo" ReturnType="int">
  <Parameter Name="fechaNacimiento" Type="datetime" Mode="In" />
</Function>
```

This static method in a class:

```
    [EdmFunction("ControlVisitas3Model.Store", "ObtieneEdad")]
    public static int? ObtieneEdad(DateTime fechaNacimiento)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Direct calls are not supported.");
    }
```

And finally, I am trying to use in this query:

```
personas = personas.Where(p => !p.PersonaFechaNacimiento.HasValue ? false : DataWare.Persona.ObtieneEdad(p.PersonaFechaNacimiento.Value) >= edadMinima && DataWare.Persona.ObtieneEdad(p.PersonaFechaNacimiento.Value) <= edadMaxima);
```

Where "personas" is an IQuerable.

When that query is run, this exception is thrown:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] ObtieneEdad(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

What may be missing here?

I have followed instructions from this web page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/how-to-call-custom-database-functions

Comment: It should work fine. Hard to tell where exactly your mistake is, because there are a lot of options, like wrong model name in `EdmFunction` attribute, wrong placement of `Function` xml node (for example, not inside SSDL part) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this way:

- Added this method to the context class (which inherits DbContext):

  ```
  [DbFunction("ControlVisitas3Model.Store", "ObtieneEdad")]
  public int ObtieneEdad(DateTime fechaNacimiento)
  {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
  ```
- Called it this way:

  ```
  personas = personas.Where(p => p.PersonaFechaNacimiento.HasValue && db.ObtieneEdad(p.PersonaFechaNacimiento.Value) >= edadMinima && db.ObtieneEdad(p.PersonaFechaNacimiento.Value) <= edadMaxima);
  ```

Regards

Jaime